# Preset Options in Object and see if it doesn't exist in allowed properties

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to make a preset list of options that are allowed in my object list. Here is code

```
var a = function(cmd, options){
     var objList = [options.search ,options.demand];

    if(!(options in objList)){
      console.warn('Not an Allowed * in the options Property');
      }
 };
```

or should I do

```
var a = function(cmd, options){
     var objList = [search , demand];

    if(!(options in objList)){
      console.warn('Not an Allowed option in the options Property');
      }
 };
```

Basically what I want to do is set that `search` and `demand` are allowed options in the options Property so later than can do

```
 a('cmd',{
  search:'',
  demand:function() {
   alert('Hello');
    },
  //warn that the next option is not allowed
  quote: function() {
    alert('quote of user');
   }
  });
```

If you are having trouble understanding what I am asking please ask and I will do my best to explain a bit more.

maybe writing it like so would be better?

```
var a = function(cmd, options){
  options = {
   theme: function(color) {
    $('body').css('backgroundColor',color);
    },
   color:''
   };
 };

a('cmd',{
  theme:'#000'//though this is not working?
 });
```

Comment: Why you need this? The idea of passing arguments in an object is, that it allows you to choose which argument you want to use in a function, you can simply ignore extra properties in the `options` object.

Comment: Well because I don't want to use extra options. I am new to objects by the way. I usually use multiple object notations to create the codes that I need but I wanted to create an in depth object. maybe I could do something different with my code? by maybe making it so that `options={//more in depth object listings here?\\};` so that inside the code they do `('cmd',{ theme:'', color:'', etc });`??

Comment: Umh... You can use only the properties of `options` you need, if there are extra properties, they are garbage collected after `a` has been executed. Your edited example is not working, since you're overriding the `options` argument.

Comment: @Teemu sorry like I said new at this, extra properties such as? Like if I only state `options.theme`, `options.color`, and if someone states `start:` in the code it is garbaged?

Answer (score 2):

You could check each property in `options` against an array of allowed options like this:

```
var a = function(cmd, options){
  var allowedOptions = ["search", "demand"];

  var hasDisallowedOptions = false;

  for (option in options) {
    if(allowedOptions.indexOf(option) === -1 ) {
      hasDisallowedOptions = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  // if hasDisallowedOptions is true, then there is a disallowed option
};
```

[jsfiddle with a couple test cases/examples](http://jsfiddle.net/wyM5x/)

Comment: Ok great so it worked, though after trying multiple incorrect options in only warns of 1 incorrect option. Should I do option[options] ???

Comment: Are you trying to list all the disallowed options?

Comment: I am going to update my code to see if I can write it better as I am new to this, so I want to see if I can get it better. Then i will let you know ok

Comment: I've updated my first post at the bottom, please see this and see if I wrote correctly as it is not working like expected

Comment: @EasyBB: I updated my answer with a jsfiddle link showing how it works.

Answer (score 1):

A one idea of passing arguments in an object is, that it allows you to choose which argument you want to use in a function, you can simply ignore extra properties in the `options` object. Hence you don't need to "filter" the properties of the argument either.

Let's assume you've a function like this:

```
var a = function (cmd, options) {
    var theme = {
        backgroundColor: options.bgColor,
        color: options.color
    }
    // Do something with theme
    // Notice also, that there was no use for options.extra in this function
}
```

Then you invoke `a` like this:

```
a('cmd', {
    bgColor: '#ff0',
    color: '#000',
    extra: 'This is an extra property'
});
```

Now you can see, `extra` is not used in `a` at all, though it was a property of the anonymous object passed to `a` as an argument. Also all arguments passed to `a` are garbage collected, unless you're not going to create a closure, i.e. returning a local value or a function from `a`.